# Star Trek: Discovery timeline in relation to Next Generation and Voyager

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

I have just finished watching *Star Trek: Next Generation* and *Voyage*r they seemed to be in the same timeline and fit together.

I have now started on *ST:Discovery*.

The timeline doesn't make much sense to me because in *Voyager they had insane shield technology that Janeway's future self gave to *Voyager* before their return.

So my guess is that *Discovery* is prior in the timeline. Is my confusion because I haven't yet seen *Deep Space Nine*?

Comment: It’s generally a good idea to read the Wikipedia article about something before asking about it here, in this case the third sentence of the article on _Star Trek: Discovery_.

Comment: @MikeScott, I feel that Wikipedia would be Overkill for this question. Even the simple synopsis blurb Netflix gives you answers this question. -1

Answer (score 2):

Discovery is meant to be 10 years before the original Star Trek - Kirk and Spock which itself is set in 2265-2269 - about a 100 years after Archer, T Pol and Enterprise set in 2151-2161. TNG is set in 2364-2370, DS9 is set in 2369-2375 and Voyager is meant to be set in 2371-2378 All these are set in the original timeline. I belive that when JJ Abrams reboted the Series in 2009, an alternative timeline was introduced. I'm sorry but as a life long Trekkie, I'm afraid Discovery isn't floating my boat at all.

Comment: Cheets paul you are right i will watch deep space nin and wait for a few more episodes to come.out on discovery but it doesn't live up to the rest but in saying that it took me a while to get into voyager after the next gen but by the 3rd season i was part of the voyager crew amd devastated that they got home